# How can I navigate to parent's sibling from child?

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I'm trying to redirect unauthorized users to the home page from other routes. My routes in app-routing.module look like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    canActivate: [MainPageAuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: RootComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

As you can see I have an `AuthGuard` for my purposes, here's the code:

```js
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService,
      ) {
      }

      public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if (!this.authService.isAuthorized) {
          this.router.navigate(['']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
```

**And the thing is**: 
When I'm on the route '*/dashboard/settings*' and I'm logging out - I'm redirected on '*/dashboard*'
When I'm on the route '*/dashboard*' and I'm logging out - I'm redirected on the *home* page

And I've already tried many different ways to navigate, even (just to check) window.open() works the same way: properly in '/dashboard' and not working in it's children

Comment: Can you post what you're doing when you log out as a user? And what is the home page?

Comment: @bjdose yeah, by the home page I mean the first route ('', MainPageComponent).
And when logging out I'm clearing tokens in the AuthService, so the authService.isAuthorized becomes false

Comment: Can you post the `MainPageAuthGuard`?

Comment: @bjdose added to the question. But the problem remains even when I remove this guard from app-routing.module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to replace canActivate guard with canActivateChild guard.

'/dashboard' route now looks like this:

```
path: 'dashboard',
component: DashboardComponent,
canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
```

And AuthGuard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {
  }

  public canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                          state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isAuthorized) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```